# Find and sort by file size

Tags: find, sort

I have this command to find files larger than 2 KB and sort by size:

```
find . -size +2k -name *.log -printf "%p \t%k kb\n" | ls -lS
```

but the `ls -lS` gives the files that are less than 2 KB also.

How can I display the names and sizes of the files that are larger than 2 KB,
sorted by size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
 find . -size +2k  -printf "%p \t%k kb\n" | sort -k2n
```

Comment: what does k2n do?

Comment: Assuming none of the file names contain blanks or newline characters.

Comment: Note that strictly speaking, that sorts by _disk usage_, not by _size_, though that's likely what the OP wants anyway.

Comment: -k2n sets the sort key to the second field, to be interpreted numerically.

Answer (score 2):

The ls command will list the current directory, not read something from stdin.

Use

```
find . -size +2k -name *.log -printf "%s %p \t%k kb\n" | sort -n | sed -e '/^[0-9]* //'
```

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
printf '%s\n' **/*.log(DLK+2oLe'[
  stat -A blk +block -- $REPLY && REPLY+=" $((blk / 2)) KiB"]')
```

That reports the *disk usage* of the log files whose *size* is greater that 2048, ordered by *size*.